# Does sharepoint designer 2010 require Office 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Can I install SharePoint Designer 2010 on a machine that doesn't have Office 2010?  I can't seem to find the requirements for SPD2010...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can install SPD 2010 without Office 2010.